# MongoDB server not starting after crash

Tags: mongodb

I have a single server configuration of MongoDB 4.0.5, running on Amazon AMI. Due to some heavy load of reads and writes it crashed (believed to be because of out of memory error). Since the crash, any attempt to bring back the mongo server fails.

In the mongod.log file the following output is written over and over again (as the server tries to start itself in a loop):

```
...
2020-06-24T16:38:23.636+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /media/mongovol/data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-06-24T16:38:23.637+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7277M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2020-06-24T16:38:24.285+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593016704:285413][4793:0x7f6559820b40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 9198/127616 to 9199/256
2020-06-24T16:38:24.285+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593016704:285682][4793:0x7f6559820b40], txn-recover: Recovering log 9198 through 9199
2020-06-24T16:38:24.341+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593016704:341106][4793:0x7f6559820b40], txn-recover: Recovering log 9199 through 9199
2020-06-24T16:38:24.387+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593016704:387027][4793:0x7f6559820b40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 5ef2be9d0000001e
2020-06-24T16:38:24.397+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(1592966813, 30)
2020-06-24T16:38:24.397+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Triggering the first stable checkpoint. Initial Data: Timestamp(1592966813, 30) PrevStable: Timestamp(0, 0) CurrStable: Timestamp(1592966813, 30)
2020-06-24T16:38:24.408+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting OplogTruncaterThread local.oplog.rs
2020-06-24T16:38:24.408+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 10031 records totaling to 6874042080 bytes
2020-06-24T16:38:24.408+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Scanning the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
2020-06-24T16:38:31.032+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/media/mongovol/data/diagnostic.data'
2020-06-24T16:38:31.033+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Rollback ID is 1
2020-06-24T16:38:31.033+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Recovering from stable timestamp: Timestamp(1592966813, 30) (top of oplog: { ts: Timestamp(1592967376, 1), t: 8 }, appliedThrough: { ts: Timestamp(0, 0), t: -1 }, TruncateAfter: Timestamp(0, 0))
2020-06-24T16:38:31.033+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Starting recovery oplog application at the stable timestamp: Timestamp(1592966813, 30)
2020-06-24T16:38:31.033+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Replaying stored operations from { : Timestamp(1592966813, 30) } (exclusive) to { : Timestamp(1592967376, 1) } (inclusive).
2020-06-24T16:38:32.070+0000 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
2020-06-24T16:39:53.692+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2020-06-24T16:39:53.692+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-06-24T16:39:53.692+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2020-06-24T16:39:53.692+0000 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] shutting down replication subsystems
2020-06-24T16:41:24.479+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
```

Running *mongod --repair* on the db folder ends successfully but still the server fails to start with the same error.

How can I recover this server?

Comment: Is the process doing something? Looks like something may be killing it, stop that thing from killing the process and let the recovery complete.

Comment: `got signal 15` means that something external to the mongod process sent it a term signal.  Check that the systemd service file and the mongod configuration file use the same location for the pidfile.

Answer (score 0):

After the comments I tried to start the server manually by running the *mongod* process directly instead of starting it using *systemctl*. After a while the database has been recovered and I was able to stop it and start it again using the systemctl. Appears that when trying to start the server as a service after a crush might not give it enough time to recover properly, but once it has been recovered there is no problem to continue starting it as usual.